# Struggling to implement Google Maps Clustering

Tags: google-maps

I work at an Alarm systems company and we have an option in our service managing software to export lets say next months alarm system maintenance's that are due to a google map.  Extremely useful for when trying to book everything close by for an engineers day.  My HTML and CSS knowledge is very good however my JS is pretty much guess work and yet to really learn it!

Could one of you very knowledgeable people on here help me out with adding Google Map pin CLUSTERING to this existing exported code?  To save time and space I have only included one location in the example code.  I have spent hours and hours reading up on it but are still struggling.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
["Mr Random Person  OPD/0100", "Some Street<br>In England<br>TOWN<br>County<br>BB11 2AA", 51.5137737, -1.1424908, "FE7569"]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5137737,-1.1424908),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var pinColor = locations[i][4];

      var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
          new google.maps.Size(21, 43),
          new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

      var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
          new google.maps.Size(40, 37),
          new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          new google.maps.Point(12, 35));

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
        map: map,
        icon: pinImage,
        shadow: pinShadow
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
         var content = '<div id="content">'+
             '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                 '</div>'+
                 '<h2 id="secondHeading" class="secondHeading">'+
                locations[i][0]+
             '</h2>'+
               '<div id="bodyContent">'+
              locations[i][1]+
             '</div>'+
             '</div>';

          infowindow.setContent(content);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am basically trying to achieve this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers/markerclustererfull.png

Comment: You failed to mention what the specific problem with the code is. What does it do and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: In this code I have removed my attempts to add map marker clustering.  I need to group multiple markers when zoomed out to show the quantity within an area.

Comment: Here is an example - https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers/markerclustererfull.png

Answer (score 0):

You can try a cluster in php. Basically create a grid and sort the points into the grid cells:http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/introduction-to-marker-clustering-with-google-maps.